# How to use ColorAnimation for each ListViewItem after certain time of adding a new item

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, listviewitem, coloranimation

I am working on a Windows 10 app. I have used a ListView which gets its items via a textbox. I need to make the ListViewItems blink (or simply change color) after some time. I have used a DispatcherTimer. When I run the application, the storyboard is executed, but only the header blinks and not the ListView. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Here is the XAML part:

```
<Page
x:Class="listViewAnimation.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:listViewAnimation"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="listView" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ListViewItem.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" From="Red" To="YellowGreen" Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                        AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="Black">
    <ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="566" Margin="428,128,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1357" Foreground="#FFF90000" Header="blah blah">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" >
                <Style.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="370"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Digital-7 Mono"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="630"/>


                </Style.Setters>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsStackPanel
                    Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>


    </ListView>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="369,899,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="14" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Width="194"/>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="631,925,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FFFBFBFE" BorderBrush="#FFFBFBFE" Click="button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

The code behind is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace listViewAnimation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {

        DispatcherTimer t = new DispatcherTimer();
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            listView.Items.Add(textBox.Text);
           manip();
        }

        private void manip()
        {

            t.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
            t.Tick += T_Tick;
            t.Start();
        }

        private void T_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            Storyboard1.Begin();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Also, I am new to Windows 10 development.

Comment: Do you want to animate only added ListViewItem or all the items?

Comment: Only to added ListViewItem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the Target property to added `ListViewItem` not to `ListView`

```
 <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
            <ColorAnimation  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ListViewItem.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" From="Red" To="YellowGreen" Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                        AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
        </Storyboard>

 ListViewItem item;
        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            listView.Items.Add(textBox.Text);
            listView.UpdateLayout();
         item =  (ListViewItem) listView.ContainerFromIndex(listView.Items.Count-1);
            manip();
        }

    private void T_Tick(object sender, object e)
            {
                if (item != null)
                {
                  Storyboard1.Stop();//If animation is running for previously added item
                  Storyboard.SetTarget(Storyboard1, item);
                  Storyboard1.Begin();
                    t.Stop();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This solves my problem. Much appreciated.

Comment: This solution does help, but it applies the animation to the last added ListViewItem only. What could be done to apply animation on each ListViewItem separately (So that two items could be animated simultaneously or separately so that the animation on one item does not affect the other? ) For example, if item1 is blinking and item2 is added, item1 does not stop blinking.

Comment: Thats what i asked before. You said you want it to only added ListViewItem

Comment: To add it to all ListViewItems you have to use different storyboards. and get all the listviewitems reference seperately

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you the first time. By reference you mean, I have to set the TargetName Property inside storyboard to specific item like listView.Items[0] ?

Comment: You have to set Target Property. listviewitem  you ll get from ContainerFromItem method. What kind of animation you have to do every time you add the item? Is it same blinking animation?

Comment: Yes it is a blinking animation. I have mentioned it in the question as well. Thank you so much for you input. It has been very encouraging and helpful.